# I'm having troubles to move to other columns in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have an Excel workbook which has in it a worksheet 1 (ws1) the column A with text like:
[image: Original file]

and I need to find several words contained in the same workbook but in another worksheet ws2:
[image: words to find]

The result that I want is:
[image: result expected]

In VBA I'm doing:

ActiveWorksheet is ws2

```
Row = 2
Col = "A"
Row2 = 2
Col2 = "B"
x = 1
Range(Col & Row).Activate
ws1.Range(Col2 & 1).Value = ActiveCell.Value
While ActiveCell.Value <> 0
        While ws1.Range("AA" & Row2).Value <> 0
            If InStr(1, ws1.Range("AA" & Row2), ActiveCell.Value) Then
                 ws1.Range(Col2 & Row2).Value = ActiveCell.Value
                   Row2 = Row2 + 1
            Else
                ws1.Range(Col2 & Row2).Value = "N/A"
                ws1.Range(Col2 & Row2).Interior.Color = RGB(1, 150, 150)
                Row2 = Row2 + 1
            End If
        Wend
        Col2=Col2+1
        Row = Row + 1
        Range(Col & Row).Activate
Wend
```

But I'm having troubles to move to the second & + columns and start the checking over again.
Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can't increment the string "A" to "B" by saying "A"+1. Instead of referencing locations with `Range(col & row).Value` use `Cells(row, col)`. When you do this, you can reference the column by number e,g.: `Range("A1")` is the same as `Cells(1,1)` and is simpler to increment

Comment: Do you absolutely need this to be done with VBA? The following formula would do the same job: `=IFERROR(IF(FIND(B$1,$A2)>0,B$1,""),"n/a")`

Comment: Thank you @Marcucciboy2 worked just fine!

Comment: Thank you cybernetic.nomad! unfortunately needed to be done in VBA because that part is inside a bigger macro!

Comment: @user9910379 did you get this all sorted out then or do you still need some help?

Comment: All sorted, started to use ws1.Cells(Row,Col).Value, etc and worked just fine! Thanks a lot @Marcucciboy2!